# Nested array in Rest api comes as concatenated string

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, postman, rest

My request body has nested list like below.

```
    ***Test:{
         Mylist:[[34,34343], 
         [45,6734]]
        }***
```

But my Test object received in my controller comes as

```
    **Test:{
       Mylist:[["3434343"],["456734"]]
      }**
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add your code?

Answer (score 0):

Removed the moxy jars and worked fine